# Query EC2 cloudwatch metrics for an autoscaling group from a thread

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

Lets say I have crontask.py that reads from a list of services running on AWS and spawns new metrics threads for each service to go out and grab the CPUUtilization for their respective auto scaling groups and perform some threshold calculations. This was working fine previously when I used the usual:

```
client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
```

And then performed:

```
response = client.get_metric_statistics()
```

The problem occurs when I have dozens of these threads running at once, it appears a separate session is required for each thread. So in the process of re-working things I've ran into some issues.

There may be a simpler way to do this but I filter the instances by their identifier tag and extract the auto scaling group name:

```
session = boto3.Session(region_name=os.getenv("AWS_REGION") or 'us-east-1')
        ec2 = session.resource('ec2')
        instances = ec2.instances.filter(
            Filters=[
                {
                    'Name': 'tag:Name',
                    'Values': [nameTag]
                }
            ],
            MaxResults=5,
        )
```

With the auto scaling group name, I then query cloudwatch for the CPUUtilization metric:

```
cloudwatch = session.resource('cloudwatch')
        metric = cloudwatch.Metric('AWS/EC2',metricVar)
        response = metric.get_statistics(
            Namespace = 'AWS/EC2',
            Period = 300,
            StartTime = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(seconds = 600),
            EndTime = datetime.utcnow(),
            MetricName = metricVar,
            Statistics=['Average'], Unit='Percent',
            Dimensions = [
                {'Name': 'InstanceId', 'Value': asgName}
            ])
```

I get a 200 code response but the Datapoints `[]` is empty:
`{'Label': 'CPUUtilization', 'Datapoints': [],`

So hopefully someone can chime in here and let me know what I've done wrong or perhaps a better way to obtain this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be many reason, but one apparent issue is that your **metric dimensions are incorrect**:

```
Dimensions = [
                {'Name': 'InstanceId', 'Value': asgName}
            ]
```

For dimension of `InstanceId` you [should be](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html#ec2-cloudwatch-dimensions) using instance id, not autoscaling name.

For autoscaling name, the dimension name is `AutoScalingGroupName`.

Thus, please double check all the names, dimensions and namespaces you are trying to use.

Comment: I did notice that but it was returning results before so I left it alone. I just tried to change it over and it's now returning results, so that indeed appears to be correct.

Using `client.get_metric_statistics()` returns no results if I try to use `AutoScalingGroupName`. And if I continue to use `InstanceId` I get the same data that I'm now getting from the AutoScalingGroupName from `metric.get_statistics()`

Comment: @doublesaces As I wrote, there could be many other reasons. What is `metricVar` for example? Its value could be incorrect?  Also does it work  when you use a single thread, or when you use AWS CLI with the same parameters as in boto3 script?

Comment: "metricVar": "CPUUtilization"

Single/multithread seems to make no difference in terms of getting datapoint back. The errors occur during instantiation of the client as it is not thread safe, which I believe I have solved using a thread lock on that section of code. I initially tested using the CLI however all my testing lately has been with boto3 so I can't comment on that part at the moment.

Comment: @doublesaces Thanks for letting me know and accepting the answer. If you will have more info, please let me know as well.

Comment: It resolves the main portion of my question, the 'Name' must be 'AutoScalingGroupName'. Although, that does seem to raise more questions as to why my initial method required InstanceId. Perhaps that is a question for another day. Thank you.

Comment: @doublesaces No problem. Don't know why it would work previously. Interesting.

Comment: Turns out my old code was catching the InstanceId and not the ASG. Its all fixed now.

Comment: @doublesaces Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
  client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
    response = client.get_metric_statistics(
            Namespace='AWS/EC2',
            MetricName='CPUUtilization',
            Dimensions=[
                {
                'Name': 'AutoScalingGroupName',
                'Value': 'asg-production'
                },
            ],
            StartTime=startTime,
            EndTime=endTime,
            Period=60,
            Statistics=[
                'Average',
            ],
            Unit='Percent',
        )
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).